# Upload formdata and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I am trying to write a script with jQuery that can loop through all input-fields and append it to the formData object.

I have done the same before in 'normal' JS and that works fine - but I don't understand why this doesn't work with jQuery instead...

It does not append anything to the formData object at all...

Here is my old JS example:

```
<input type="file" name="upload_file" onchange="post_form('target_url.asp');">
<script type="application/javascript">
function post_form(target_url) {
  var inp = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var i_a;
  var fil_x;
  var str_val = new FormData();
  for (i_a = 0; i_a < inp.length; i_a++) {
    if (inp[i_a].type == "file") {
      for (fil_x = 0; fil_x < inp[i_a].files.length; fil_x++) {
        str_val.append("file", inp[i_a].files[fil_x], inp[i_a].files[fil_x].name);
      }
    }
  }
  pgf = new XMLHttpRequest();
  pgf.open("POST", target_url, true);
  pgf.send(str_val);
}
</script>
```

And here is my new script which should do the same but with jQuery instead... But it doesn't work - nothing is send to the server... I don't think it's actually appending it to formData...

```
<input type="file" name="upload_file" onchange="post_form('target_url.asp');">
<script type="application/javascript">
function post_form(target_url) {
  var r_data = new FormData();
  $(document).find("input, select, textarea").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("type") !== "checkbox" && $(this).attr("type") !== "radio") {
      if ($(this).attr("name") != undefined) {
        r_data.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this).val());
      }
    } else {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        if ($(this).attr("name") != undefined) {
          r_data.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this).val());
        }
      }
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: target_url,
    data: r_data,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
  });
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have searched and tried a lot of different examples with jQuery but I cant see why this is different - and why its not working...

Thanks

Comment: You should call jQuery before your custom code.

Comment: If it works in native JS, I don't see why you want to refactor it in jQuery. jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: @Terry You can't use `serialize()` when there are `file` inputs.

Comment: @Azametzin That's not necessary since the function is called when the user submits, do the DOM will be loaded.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, in this case, but who knows where else he would use jQuery

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: can you paste your html here?